# Autofac: Get ServiceLifetime by IComponentRegistration

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

What is the right way to get `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLifetime` by `Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration`?
In other words, how to implement this method?

```
private static Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLifetime GetServiceLifetime(
    Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration)
{
    ...
}
```

Note: I'm using Autofac `4.9.4` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `IComponentRegistration.Sharing` property is `None`, then the `ServiceLifetime` is `Transient`.

If that same property is `Shared`, then if the `Lifetime` property is an instance of `RootScopeLifetime` (literally `Lifetime is RootScopeLifetime`), then the `ServiceLifetime` is `Singleton`.

The `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` value is effectively the 'else' case here.

Note that the Microsoft DI library does not have the concept of [Instance per Matching Scopes](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-matching-lifetime-scope), so there isn't a 100% equivalence, but it's close.

Comment: Yes, this way I am already using, just want to be sure if I am right. Thanks